# amqp client doesn't show that RabbitMQ server connection is blocked

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqplib

I run RabbitMQ image in docker-compose like this:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    networks:
      - private
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.0-beta.3-management
    ports: 
      - 15672:15672
```

Then connect to via other Node.js app like this:

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');

this._connection = await amqp.connect(xxxxxx);
console.log(this._connection.blocked);

this._connection.on("blocked", (reason) => {
    console.log("!!!! connection blocked");
});
```

It works fine but few questions:

1. Why `console.log(this._connection.blocked);` outputs `undefined`;
2. How do I detect that connection is already blocked when I start the client? I.e. service is out of resources and RabbitMA manager says that connection is in 'blocking' state right after it connected. This is why `this._connection.on("blocked"` doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check the [document](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html) and [source](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/search?q=blocked&unscoped_q=blocked) of amqplib, register event callback is the only way to receive `Blocked Connection Notifications`, amqplib connection hasn't use some member variable to show blocking state.

[From offical document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/connection-blocked.html), I am not sure whether this mean there is no notification when you connect to an already blocked server:

> If before the connections are unblocked the node also starts running low on disk space, another connection.blocked will not be sent